# Why this is not working printing star pattern in while loop by using javascript or NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop

I'm learning javaScript, i tried to left aligned star pattern using while loop instead of For, but its not working as i expected!

Following is my program:

```
let n = 5, i = 1 , j = 0
let str =""
while(i <= n)  
{
while(j < i)  
    {
        j++
        str += "*"  
    }
 i++
 str +="\n"  
}
console.log(str)

result:

* 
* 
* 
* 
* 

Im expecting this:

* 
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reassign the `j` to 0 again before each second loop:

```js
let n = 5,
  i = 1,
  j = 0
let str = ""

while (i <= n) {
  j = 0
  while (j < i) {
    j++
    str += "*"
  }
  i++
  str += "\n"
}

console.log(str)
```